# Why is the rank of elliptic curves isogeny invariant?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, isogeny

Let $E/K$ and $E'/K$ be an elliptic curve over a field.

If there exists an  be an isogeny of elliptic curve $\phi: E\to E'$, why can we say $rank(E/K)=rank(E'/K)$ ?

Here, I define as non constant morphism which sends base point to base point.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel of the isogeny is a group of points of finite order equal to the degree. Therefore the free part of the group of points on $E$ is the same size after the isogeny: it only affects the torsion part.

Comment: While this answer is rightish, it doesn't tell me what to do when the torsion subgroup is a Galois stable set of points which are not themselves rational.

Comment: The intersection with the free part is still trivial

Comment: Indeed, but imo it doesn't go without saying that the Galois action on the free part doesn't change. Of course this is nearly obvious since the image of a point of inf. order is still Galois stable because the isogeny is rational, but it bears mentioning I think